# find -exec doesn't recognize argument

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to count the total lines in the files within a directory. To do this I am trying to use a combination of find and wc. However, when I run `find . -exec wc -l {}\;`, I recieve the error `find: missing argument to -exec`. I can't see any apparent issues, any ideas?

Comment: You missed a space: `find . -exec wc -l {} \;` (space before `\;`).

Comment: I am not a clever man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need a space between `{}` and `\;`

```
find . -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Note that if there are any sub-directories from the current location, `wc` will generate an error message for each of them that looks something like that:

```
wc: ./subdir: Is a directory
```

To avoid that problem, you may want to tell `find` to restrict the search to files :

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Another note: good idea using the `-exec` option . Too many times people pipe commands together thinking to get the same result, for instance here it would be :

```
 find . -type f | xargs wc -l
```

The problem with piping commands in such a manner is that it breaks if any files has spaces in it. For instance here if a file name was "a b" , `wc` would receive "a" and then "b" separately and you would obviously get 2 error messages: `a: no such file` and `b: no such file`.

Unless you know for a fact that your file names never have any spaces in them (or non-printable characters), if you do need to pipe commands together, you need to tell *all* the tools you are piping together to use the NULL character (\0) as a separator instead of a space. So the previous command would become:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Comment: And, even better, POSIX stipulates that using `+` in place of `';'` (or `\;`) works more or less the same as using `xargs`; `find` groups a bunch of file names together to run the command once per N file names (where N is not a controllable quantity, but depends on the maximum length of an argument list and the length of the file names).

Answer (score 1):

With version 4.0 or later of `bash`, you don't need your `find` command at all:

```
shopt -s globstar
wc -l **/*
```

There's no simple way to skip directories, which as pointed out by Gui Rava you might want to do, unless you can differentiate files and directories by name alone. For example, maybe directories never have `.` in their name, while all the files have at least one extension:

```
wc -l **/*.*
```